# ¿Como descargar archivo PDF con ruta especifica dentro del disco net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

espero me puedan apoyar, estoy tratando de descargar un archivo pdf que yo guardo en mi disco local C al momento de crear un usuario, la ruta la obtengo y la guardo en un campo en mi BD. El problema es que no me sale ningun error y cuando pruebo mi aplicación, entra bien al método pero no me descarga el archivo que necesito.

Asi es como se guarda la ruta en mi BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi vista creo un boton de esta manera:

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" asp-action="DescargarCv" asp-route-idCandidato="@candidato.IdCandidato"><i class="bi bi-file-earmark-pdf"></i></a>
```

Esta es mi método de mi controlador:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DescargarCv(int idCandidato)
    {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        var idUsuario = servicioUsuario.ObtenerIdUsuario();
        var candidato = await repositorioCandidato.ObtenerCandidatoPorId(idCandidato, idUsuario);

        if(candidato is null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NoEncontrado", "Home");
        }

        webClient.DownloadFile(candidato.RutaCV, "DescargaCV.pdf");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Estoy utilizando `WebClient.DownloadFile`, el problema es que no me sale ningun mensaje de error, ya lo hice debugg pero tampoco me sale algun mensaje de error en especifico que me pueda apoyar y tampoco me descarga el archivo. Espero me puedan apoyar en comentarme si tengo algo mal y se los agradeceria.

Answer (score 0):

Ya vi cual es el error, resulta que esta descargando los archivos dentro de la carpeta de mi proyecto. Solo Es especificarle la ruta en donde quieras que aparezcan las descargas.

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DescargarCv(int idCandidato)
    {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        var idUsuario = servicioUsuario.ObtenerIdUsuario();
        var candidato = await repositorioCandidato.ObtenerCandidatoPorId(idCandidato, idUsuario);

        if(candidato is null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NoEncontrado", "Home");
        }

        try
        {
            webClient.DownloadFile(candidato.RutaCV, "C:\\Users\\" + candidato.NombreArchivo);
            TempData["mensaje"] = "El CV se descargo correctamente, favor de revisar en tu ruta: " + candidato.RutaCV;
        }
        catch  (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["mensajeError"] = ex;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás especificando que `candidato.RutaCV` tiene el valor de la ruta, pero también el nombre del archivo:

C:\DocumentosCH\CurriculumsCandidatos\Curriculum.pdf

Cuando usas [WebClient.DownloadFile(string address, string fileName)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-7.0) el primer parámetro es la Uri o la ruta donde se descargará el archivo, el segundo parámetro es el nombre. Por lo tanto, el problema es que estas definiendo en la ruta también el nombre del archivo, lo cual es incorrecto.

```
   webClient.DownloadFile(@"C:\DocumentosCH\CurriculumsCandidatos\", "DescargaCV.pdf");
```